# Run script at startup?

Tags: command-line, startup-applications

I have following two line of commands that needs to be run when the computer starts:

```
killall syndaemon 
syndaemon -i 0.5 -KRd
```

I created one entry in startup application and added following command:

```
killall syndaemon & syndaemon -i 0.5 -KRd
```

But it doesn't get executed.

Tried putting the sleep for few seconds also in the command but no luck.

Comment: If it works from terminal, it definitely works with a break form startup, but most likely your break is too small, making it overruled after your break. Try 15 seconds, making it smaller until you have your limit. This is typically such a command.

Comment: Rajeev, please post the exact command you used, setting the break. The correct format is in the link I provided, but just to check.

Comment: @JacobVlijm - I tried the answer that was suggested in provided link above but still it didn't work.

Comment: Rajeev, again, please post the exact command you ran including break.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, I tried following command:                                                          /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && killall syndaemon & syndaemon -i 0.5 -KRd"

Comment: @RajeevJayaswal please replace `syndaemon & syndaemon` by `syndaemon && syndaemon`

Comment: Thanks @JacobVlijm for pointing out the mistake in command. That worked!!.

Comment: @RajeevJayaswal you're welcome. It's always a single character that spoils the fun :). Could you mark your question as a dupe?

Comment: Thanks JacobVlijm, I think someone already marked the answer as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a crontab entry, writing down "@reboot" as the time:

```
@reboot /usr/local/my_script.sh
```

[Source: Cyberciti](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/)